# Angular 2 - Invalid Pipe Argument: '' for pipe 'Async Pipe'

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

In component.html

```
<select name="select1" *ngIf="optionsArr | async">
    <option *ngFor="let option of optionsArr">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

In component.ts

```
export class ComponentX implements OnInit {
optionsArr = [];

constructor(private service : ServiceX) { }

ngOnInit() { 
   this.optionsArr = this.service.getJSON(filepath);
}

}
```

In service.ts

```
export class ServiceX {
   constructor() {}
   getJSON(filepath){
      return Observable.create((observer:any) =>{
          //retrieve JSON here
          observer.next(jsonArr);
          observer.complete();
      });
   }
}
```

I have this error:
Invalid Pipe Argument: '' for pipe 'Async Pipe'

Comment: Observable must return array, may be somewhere you are returning obj. Please check.

Comment: Apply pipe on *ngFor="let option of optionsArr | async"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `*ngFor` references the observable and not the data within.
In your `ngIf`, you pipe the array correctly, but if you want to use the values from it you should declare the result as a variable, do this: `optionsArr | async as options` <- Note the `as` keyword. Then proceed to use `options` in the child elements as a reference to the array. So your `*ngFor` would become `*ngFor="let option of options"`

Comment: I see! I missed options in the child elements.